# enable button when checkbox checked in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When i click on checkbox I am calling controller function and in that I am setting value true, but it is not enabled.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" change="{!c.Showhide}" />
    <p>I have read and agree to the Terms </p>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Continue" aura:id="disableenable" disabled="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
({
    Showhide : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.disabled",false);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the checkbox value in `Showhide` function, you need to use `event.getSource().get('v.value')`.

And with `component.find("disableenable")` you can get the button for disabling or you can have an additional attribute store the state and use it. I like the `component.find` way.

No changes in your component, here is the controller method in action:

```
({
    Showhide : function(component, event, helper) {
        let checkBoxState = event.getSource().get('v.value');
        console.log(event.getSource().get('v.value'));
        component.find("disableenable").set("v.disabled", !checkBoxState);
    }
})
```

Component unchanged:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" change="{!c.Showhide}" />
    <p>I have read and agree to the Terms </p>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Continue" aura:id="disableenable" disabled="true"/>
</aura:component>
```